# Bootstrap tags revisited

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

There's a world of ambiguity and mis-tagging between [bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap) [bootstrapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrapping) and [twitter-bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap) [twitter-bootstrap-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap-2) [twitter-bootstrap-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap-3) [twitter-bootstrap-4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap-4). Can we sort it?

### The Issues

1. [bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap) and [bootstrapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrapping) are stated as for talking about bootstrapping in terms of computer start-up, however the vast majority of questions tagged with it instead refer to the popular [Bootstrap Framework](https://getbootstrap.com/) - which is currently denoted on SO as [twitter-bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap).
2. Bootstrap the framework is no longer named 'Twitter Bootstrap', now just 'Bootstrap' after a split with Twitter, and thus the tag name we're using for it is outdated.

### The Stats

I did a quick count up of the last 50 questions tagged with [bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap), and [bootstrapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrapping), where the mis-tagging issues are most rampant.

- 38% of [bootstrapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrapping) questions refer to Bootstrap the framework, and should not be tagged as such.
- **90%** of [bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap) refer to Bootstrap the framework, and supposedly should not be tagged as such.

### A Solution

This is a problem that has been brought up a few times before, but never yet been sorted. [1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125823/the-bootstrap-tag-is-ambiguous) [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/162023/bootstrap-tag-again) [3](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191499/is-it-time-to-branch-the-twitter-bootstrap-tag). Despite being clearly stated in the tag wiki's for [bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap) and [bootstrapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrapping), questions are still constantly tagged 'incorrectly'. With 15-20 questions a day now hitting [bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap) - I also think it's too big to manually clean up now and again.

I'd suggest the following:

1. [twitter-bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap),[twitter-bootstrap-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap-2) and [twitter-bootstrap-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap-3) are renamed [bootstrap-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap-framework),[bootstrap-framework-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap-framework-2) and [bootstrap-framework-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap-framework-3). Bootstrap framework was a tag name suggested [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/191501/233816) - and I can't think of a better name. Another option is to make [bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap) itself refer to the framework, but then there's still a level of ambiguity.
2. All questions about bootstrap startup processes are tagged under [bootstrapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrapping). There's an argument against that [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/146536/233816), but in my opinion, now the bootstrap framework has got so big, it no longer works as a standalone tag, and there's a greater need. The [relevant Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping) is named 'bootstrapping' - so I don't think it can be too far from what we want it for.
3. [bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap) is burninated. Although perhaps not, if we decide to instead tag all Bootstrap-framework questions with it.
4. I'm not entirely sure how synonym tags work in SO, but if it's appropriate, [twitter-bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap) et al. should be synonyms of our new [bootstrap-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap-framework)* tags, as although 'Twitter Bootstrap' is not an official name, I imagine the library will still be referred to as such for a few years yet.
5. Hopefully questions tagged both [bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap)* and [twitter-bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap)* can have the [bootstrap] tag manually removed, as I'm not sure of any situation where to two topics could legitimately overlap!

Doing anything about any of this is way above the means of my puny SO reputation, but would be interested to know people's thoughts, and for a solution to be put in place. Suggestions for a better tag name than [bootstrap-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap-framework) are also welcome!

Comment: Is there any possibility of also retagging all sufficiently old questions related to the framework with a tag specific to Bootstrap v2? There are a lot of outdated answers that are no longer correct for Bootstrap v3. I imagine that the vast majority of questions asked prior to the release of Bootstrap v3.0.0 RC1 are implicitly about Bootstrap v2.

Comment: As a member of the Bootstrap core dev team, I can tell you that no, v3 is not particularly backwards-compatible.

Comment: [tag:bootstrap-popover] should probably also be merged into [tag:twitter-bootstrap]...

Comment: @Mooseman - I don't think there's a problem with having specific tags for specific language features is there?

Comment: @Chris No, but it's redundant.

Comment: For the love of God something needs to be done. Powers that be please fix this.

Comment: @j08691 This is not something that can easily be "fixed"; you can't run a simple script for it, it has to be done on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: Totally agree on renaming [bootstrap] to [bootstrapping] for the startup processes. This tags are a mess.

Comment: For the love of God something needs to be done to fix this.

Comment: If 90% of questions tagged with [bootstrap] are related to the CSS framework, I think the tag needs to change, it's that simple, synomise it with [bootstrap-framework] and let's be done with this.

Comment: I've seen people excessively tagging their questions: [twitter-bootstrap], [bootstrap]. Something must be done, how are people going to ask questions really about bootstraping now?

Comment: The bootstrap tag is back, and too active to kill off again by retagging. What do we do now?

Comment: It appears that `bootstrap-4` is actually the [recommended tag on the official bootstrap site](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap#community).

Answer (score 34):

As the Bootstrap Framework originated at Twitter, but is not named Twitter Bootstrap (anymore) I believe the tag should be:

[bootstrap-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap-framework)

And components of the framework should follow suit:

[bootstrap-framework-xxx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap-framework-xxx)

Comment: I don't think components of a framework deserver a tag on their own, those of angularJS were burninated after all.

Answer (score 18):

Okay, something needs to be done about this.
**[About 98% of all new `bootstrap` questions are about the framework!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrmo9.jpg)**
<sub>And it feels like the remaining 2% are about statistical bootstrapping.</sub>

The tag is way too ambiguous and definitely has to go.
I suggest:

#### <s>Step One</s> [Done]:

Burninate [bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap).
Retag:

- About the [web framework](http://getbootstrap.com/) => [twitter-bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap)
- About [statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(statistics)) => [statistics-bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/statistics-bootstrap)
- About the [android template/bootstrap/boilerplate thing](https://github.com/AndroidBootstrap/android-bootstrap) => [android-bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-bootstrap)
- About installers => [bootstrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrapper)
- The rest (including all legitimately tagged q's) => [bootstrapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrapping).

#### Step Two:

Apply [BAR's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/287469/2302862):

> I believe the tag should be:
>
> [bootstrap-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap-framework)
>
> And components of the framework should follow suit:
>
> [bootstrap-framework-xxx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap-framework-xxx)

Or bring some consistency into it by other means.

#### Step Three:

Blacklist [bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap)?
It has been re-created and re-burninated at least <s>three</s> four times so far!

---

Now, since this question has a significant number of upvotes, has been left to rot here for **over a year**, [other](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285138/2302862) [questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253650/2302862) get closed as duplicates of this one, and nothing has been done about it whatsoever:

Unless someone's stopping me, I'm just gonna go ahead and start with Step One myself.

<sub>Also, why does everybody have to name their shit "bootstrap"?! -.-</sub>

Comment: what about the real bootstraping questions? Do they get burninated too?

Comment: I don't think burninate is the right term here because you would want to keep `bootstrap` on the questions that actually represent the term bootstrap which has nothing to do with the responsive framework. Unless I'm wrong about what burninate means. It does mean to burn it down in a mass of flames using a delete command that is irreversible right?

Comment: No, you do not want to keep `bootstrap` at all. I've been retagging and monitoring the `bootstrap` tag for almost a month now, and 99% of new questions tagged `bootstrap` are referring to the twitter framework. We can't keep retagging them for all eternity - the tag is too ambiguous and therefore has to go. Questions that rightfully use `bootstrap` are equally well off with `bootstrapping`, which has the same meaning, but won't be used to refer to the twitter framework. And you're right about the flame inferno, but retagging may occur prior to that ;)

Comment: @EricB Just as an example, [those are the last 50 questions tagged `bootstrap`](http://i.stack.imgur.com/xrmo9.jpg), and **every single one of them** refers to `twitter-bootstrap`...

Comment: I'm starting to see what you mean lol, that's a joke, I completely understand now and it makes sense!

Comment: You incorrectly retagged valid bootstrap questions to some other nonsense... bootstrap is perfectly fine tag in terms of compilers. You messed it up. You also deleted the info in the bootstrap tag. I am not happy.

Comment: The suggest `bootstrapping` has nonsensical info. Where is the original bootstrap info?

Comment: @leppie I suppose it has been removed along with the tag (which has since been recreated though -.-), but the info was similar.

Comment: @Siguza: No, there was a proper description. Not the misinformation presented in bootstrapping.

Comment: @leppie So write a better wiki entry for [bootstrapping].  We aren't going to keep around a big problem just for a few useful bits of info.

Answer (score 1):

OK, the problem persisted. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap

**I just thought of a possible solution for similar tag issues, not too smart and automated but may work.**

**How about writing a new cleansing script for future retagging issues**. Clearly [bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap), [twitter-bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap), [bootstrap-tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap-tabs) etc needs retagging and make synonyms of or burninate minor tags.

### Step 1:

Starting the procedure, asking all users to retag **all** their asked questions which are tagged with [bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap) or with both [twitter-bootstrap-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap-2) and [twitter-bootstrap-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap-3), etc. through a wizard UI, like:

```
Are you asking for help with the web developing framework Bootstrap v.3?
http://getbootstrap.com

Or is it Bootstrap v.2?
http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/

Or is it bootstraping that means the procedure of starting up a computer or application?

[bootstrap framework 3] [bootstrap framework 2] [bootstrapping the computer] [I'm not sure]
```

Questions tagged without actions are sent for review.

### Step 2:

Make synonyms or burninate minor tags.

### Step 3:

- Implement a script asking the user if the creation of the tag is absolutely needed and state there is already a very similar tag.
- Implement a script to prevent [bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap) from ever created unless they have enough reputation.
- Implement a script to check when a question is tagged with both [bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap) and [twitter-bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap) then ask the user if it was intended and tell them info on each tag.

I'm again stressing. I think this might work for other similar problems.

Comment: Isn't burninate the wrong thing to do with `bootstrap` tag because you would still want that tag to represent questions about bootstrap (the computer related term for things other than the responsive framework bootstrap. In other news. I like step 3! Is step 1 actually possible?

Comment: @EricB Sorry, I guess I didn't express myself clear enough. I wanted minor tags like `bootstrap-tabs` to get deleted because it is too minor and very few people actually follows the tags. It would be better if they only used `twitter-bootstrap` or whatever the tag is going to get renamed like the others suggested.

Comment: Don't think that you were not clear enough, your answer is fine. It does seem a bit like a new question in the form of an answer, but maybe a solution as well. I get things wrong all the time, so it's most likely me. lol I understand what you are saying and I see now what is happening. Thanks for the clarification anyways!~

Comment: @EricB You know people, "marked as duplicate". Same discussion in same question, that's the deal ;)

Answer (score -5):

using the tag `bootstrap-framework` could lead to the same discussion here, if another framework comes out using the same name. A better solution would be to rename it to something obvious like `bootstrap-css`, to clearly show that it is related to CSS. And the currently existing tags which refer to versions of the framework aliased to it.

Comment: bootstrap is not just css

Comment: Note time of writing (v3 was still beta) and most of the JS was about to complement the styling iirc.