# Request to change tag name for Bootstrap

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

There has consistently been a large amount of accidental use of the [bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap) tag when users intend to use the far more popular [twitter-bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap).

This has been problematic enough that both tag wiki's attempt to clarify the tagging process:

> **Twitter-Bootstrap**:
>   Tag `twitter-bootstrap` and NOT "bootstrap" to ask a question about this framework.
>
> **Bootstrap**:
>   NOT TO BE CONFUSED WITH Twitter's Bootstrap CSS framework; please use the twitter-bootstrap tag.

And yet, confusion still persists because many users, especially newer ones, don't know to read the full tag description before using tags.

One solution is to make the difference between the two tags more transparent without the need for using descriptions.

### My suggestions is to rename `bootstrap` to `bootstrapping`.

This seems like a very organic fit for it's current use to refer to the process of bootstrapping, while disambiguating it from Twitter's front end framework.

Users looking for twitter's library who type in 'bootstrap' when searching for a tag will be unlikely to choose bootstrapping when twitter-bootstrap is available.  And users who are looking for bootstrapping can still easily find a tag relevant to their question.

It looks like this issue has been raised in the past, but has not yet been resolved.  This particular solution differs from previous ones by attempting to bite off much less than former overhauls.
For completeness, here's a summary of questions pertaining to bootstrap tagging issues:

- [Bootstrap tags revisited](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/250920/1366033)
- [The bootstrap tag is ambiguous](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125823/209031)
- [Bootstrap tag, again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/162023/209031)
- [Is it time to “branch” the twitter-bootstrap tag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/191499/209031)

As per the meta post: [How to rename a tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87437/how-to-rename-a-tag), I'm requesting this in the context of a discussion in case anyone wants to weigh in.