# We gave [bootstrap] the boot, but it wasn't heavy enough!

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, blocklist-request

(This question/request is a follow-up to ["Bootstrap tags revisited"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/250920) - it is **not** a dupe!)

The terribly ambiguous [bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap) tag has caused a [lot](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/250920) [of](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285138) [headache](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253650), having been used for everything from [twitter-bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap) and [statistics-bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/statistics-bootstrap) over [android-bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-bootstrap) to [bootstrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrapper) and [bootstrapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrapping), of which only the last was legitimate use.

["Bootstrap tags revisited"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/250920) has been posted early '14, and no action followed it for one and a half years, until [I took it upon myself](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/298095) to just start with burnination, since the amount of upvotes on that question was pretty high - after two months and 3'000 edits from my side, the tag was finally gone, and I suggested to blacklist it.

That suggestion [was questioned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250920/bootstrap-tags-revisited/298095#comment237304_298095) (which is a good thing):

> I don't think burninate is the right term here because you would want to keep bootstrap on the questions that actually represent the term bootstrap which has nothing to do with the responsive framework.

But [I've taken a screenshot of the newest `bootstrap` questions at a time when the tag existed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrmo9.jpg).
Judge for yourselves.

It has been re-created at least four times so far, and always gathered at least 20 questions within 24 hours.
So I'd like to make the blacklist suggestion an official request.

---

TL;DR:

[bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap) is a massively misunderstood and abused tag that keeps being re-created.
Can it be blacklisted, pretty please?

Comment: Perhaps `Give [bootstrap] the boot`?

Comment: You should put a parental warning on that image... I will have nightmares :/

Comment: I'm with @Pekka웃, provide a pun with tag burination requests.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ It has been burninate already, it's a blacklist request. And I like "give it the boot", but I feel like it doesn't quite cut "sending it to hell for all eternity".

Comment: If anyone manages to come up with a good pun that in some way involves nuclear explosions, fire, hell, demons, fire, black holes, antimatter, fire, or more fire, feel free to edit the title.

Comment: How about: `Send [bootstrap]'s sole to Beelzebub's pit.`

Comment: The current title has been officially deemed punny enough. Your request will now be considered by the powers that be.

Comment: The problem here isn't cataloguing but the end user, the end user will keep reusing bootstrap tag for anything and everything, this is why SO needs to change their db schema to accommodate do not use tags

Comment: It sounds like it's aboot time.

Comment: In  way your question is linked to this one http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298289/do-not-show-deprecated-tags-in-tag-autocomplete/298357

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Attempting to use this tag will now produce [an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?tags=bootstrap):

[image: The 'bootstrap tag is not allowed. ...]

Comment: This may backfire if [outdoors.se] decide to burninate the [shoelaces] tag.

Comment: Now I'm curious: Has there ever been a question on this site asking about the actual leather straps?

Comment: I went to the [tag:bootstrap] tag to find out, @Siguza, but...

Answer (score -4):

OP, I looked at the screenshot you provided and the majority looks like they're referring to the Bootstrap framework formerly known as Twitter Bootstrap. To blacklist the `bootstrap` tag wouldn't really solve anything, the next tag which would be abused would be `bootstrap-framework` which could still end up having questions related to some of the other tags which you stated in the OP (such as `android-bootstrap` and `statistics-bootstrap`).

I could understand blacklisting the `bootstrap` tag years ago when the framework was known as Twitter Bootstrap as the `twitter-bootstrap` tag could have been used instead then but since Bootstrap is the official name of the framework, I don't think it would be a good idea to blacklist it.

As each day passes more and more people are becoming aware of Bootstrap and probably in the near future you'll find new web developers might end up never knowing it was formerly known as Twitter Bootstrap.

When comparing `bootstrap` tag to other frameworks like Django or Ruby on Rails, those frameworks aren't known on Stack Overflow as `django-framework` or `ruby-on-rails-framework`. The most commonly known frameworks deserve their own tag with no suffix after it.

Comment: If you down vote my post, could you comment and let me know what you disagree with? Thanks people

Comment: Django and RoR are not, so far as I know, at all ambiguous in practice; there's only one Django anyone is at all likely to care about. This is very definitely **not** the case for Bootstrap; the entire premise of this discussion is that there are multiple perfectly reasonable meanings of `bootstrap` that are being muddled. Tag naming doesn't need to be "fair"; it needs to be useful.

Comment: @NathanTuggy yes there are multiple definitions of `bootstrap` but the one referred to in most developing terms is usually in reference to the Bootstrap framework. Blacklisting the tag for the most popular front end framework would just raise confusion, not lower it. Bootstrapping is different and it should have it's own tag.

Comment: Solution: write actual code instead of using Twitter Bootstrap.

Answer (score -6):

What I think is needed is 2 tags which are clearly distinct, and which will both show, so they can be compared, when a person starts to type "bootstrap"

My suggestions are:

- `bootstrap-framework`
- `bootstrapping-computer-startup`

Comment: “bootstrapping” isn’t exclusive to “computer startup”.

Comment: Are you suggesting a 3rd tag? By all means, put me out of my mystery ....

Comment: Don’t take it that way. Meta is for suggestions. People can disagree with those suggestions, which is what the voting system represents.

Comment: Fair enough. But what else _does_ bootstrapping refer to?

Comment: Wiktionary has the other common definition as “to compile the tools that will be used to compile the rest of the system or program” (https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bootstrap#English), but it’s used in a similar manner to refer to the… pre-startup? of all sorts of software. So why not just `bootstrapping`?

Comment: If that's clear enough, sure. The point of my suggestion was clarity,  so that junior web designers [or whoever] won't get confused.