# A user keeps editing in the wrong tag — bootstrap and twitter-bootstrap

Tags: discussion, review-abuse

[This user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3818739/jned29) keeps adding in the [bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap) tag, along with the [twitter-bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap) tag in instances where it isn't about bootstrap loading.

I've personally rejected 10 of these so far. Mods, can you please help?

Comment: Wait, what the hell? So there's a user adding the [bootstrap] tag too? I was just watching [someone else](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3342739/cvrebert) *remove* that tag from questions but I never saw this user in the revision history for any of those questions. In fact, now that I'm seeing this, I'm surprised they managed to avoid crossing paths.

Comment: @BoltClock YES! I saw that guy too, he must be watching 'bootstrap' to take them out and the other guy is watching 'twitter-bootstrap' to put them in!

Comment: Alright, I'm sure there's no actual malice here, just confusion when it comes to the tags (they have a lot of good edits to their credit).

Comment: [Gah, seriously?](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5420709)

Comment: Related (and suggested by the engine): http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250920/bootstrap-tags-revisited?rq=1 => there was never any conclusion as to what should be done with those tags.

Comment: I'm just here to say I succesfully resisted the urge to add the [bootstrap] tag to this post.

Comment: Maybe [bootstrap] should be synonymed to [bootstrapping] to remove confusion between the process and Twitter.

Comment: @MatthieuM. What if some other framework pops out with the same name( in different language)? I think instead of `bootstrap-framework` (as suggested in the linked post) the tag should be `bootstrap-css`.

Comment: @DaGhostmanDimitrov: That's a good idea, indeed, you may wish to propose your answer to the question I linked to so we keep the discussion in a single place.

Comment: @dav_i: unfortunately, since people rarely (if ever) read the tag description when actually tagging, I doubt it would be of much use. If you read the question I linked above, 90% of the bootstrap tags are applied to the Twitter framework.

Comment: @MatthieuM. How about burninating [bootstrap] then? Retagging to [twitter-bootstrap] and [bootstrapping] accordingly?

Comment: @dav_i: that's the subject of the question I linked, so I would redirect all suggestions there to keep the discussion in a single place. Do feel free to chime in!

Comment: @MatthieuM. I've seen people literally tag their posts with tags whose descriptions say `DO NOT USE THIS TAG` as the first sentence.

Comment: See also: [Bootstrap tags revisited](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/250920/168868).  "38% of [tag:bootstrapping] questions refer to Bootstrap the framework, and should not be tagged as such."  \*sigh\*

Comment: The problem isn't an *asker* misusing a tag, in this case it is someone bulk editing questions to put the wrong tag in.

Comment: @AstroCB: People rarely, if ever, read the tag description; they just try to put whatever word they can think of as tags and blindly follow the auto-completion.

Comment: Could we just please burninate [bootstrap] already? I mean, the free karma from correcting the tags is nice, but ultimately hollow. Trying to keep [bootstrap] in existence as something other than the frontend framework is doomed to failure; it will drown in a sea of incorrectly, lazily tagged questions.