# What's with all the bootstrap-* tags?

Tags: discussion, support, tags

The [twitter-bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap) tag is [particularly confusing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250920/bootstrap-tags-revisited) thanks to [bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap) being something completely different. Twitter Bootstrap, for those unaware, is a HTML, CSS and JavaScript framework, whereas the term bootstrap is used to refer to "*a series of procedures run when an application starts up*".

As it currently stands there are a lot of questions about the Twitter framework incorrectly tagged with the Bootstrap tag. On a daily basis I find myself editing these - as I'm sure do many other users - but nevertheless they still appear.

What probably doesn't help is that Twitter's Bootstrap has a series of *components* which over the years have all obtained their own separate tags here on Stack Overflow. For whatever reason, the only one of these to be prefixed with "twitter-" is [twitter-bootstrap-tooltip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap-tooltip):

Alas, I present to you the [bootstrap-*] tag search results:

[image: Search Result Image]

None of these relate to the technique of bootstrapping, and all instead relate to Twitter's Bootstrap framework.

I imagine a fair few of these could be synonymised with [twitter-bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap), but for conformity's sake shouldn't **all** of these tags be prefixed with "twitter-" to match the parent tag?

Comment: _"On a daily basis I find myself editing these ..."_ That is quite harmful when the tag gets repurposed. As it should be.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I'd interpret that sentence differently; I think he's just editing the questions incorrectly tagged with [tag:bootstrap] (changing the tags), or did I misunderstand you?

Comment: All those css/js/jQ questions are _correctly_ tagged with [bootstrap].

Answer (score 34):

Seeing that [twitter-bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap) has 35k questions and [bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap) has <3k, could we burn [bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap) (or reappropriate it) and merge it in to [bootstrapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrapping) and [bootstrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrapper) both of which offer less room for confusion?

The reason I suggest this is that a high percentage of what gets tagged with [bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap) is actually meant for [twitter-bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap) so the actual number of actual [bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap) questions is likely to be much lower than 3k.

Comment: That still leaves the issue that [tag:twitter-bootstrap] hasn't actually been called Twitter Bootstrap for a few years now...see the linked post for all the details there. Names like [tag:bootstrap-framework] were suggested - but I agree, bootstrap is a bit ambiguous.

Comment: Yes, moving everything that pertains to bootstrapping processes to `boostrapping` and repurposing `bootstrap` to the framework is the way to go. People searching for Bootstrap do not naturally think "twitter-bootstrap". Also, the list that the OP produced contains tags that have different reasons for existing. Some of them are refinements of `twitter-bootstrap`, like `twitter-bootstrap-tooltip`. Some are for tools that are not part of Bootstrap, like `boostrap-growl`. They  were never related to Twitter. Adding `twitter` to them would be confusing.

Comment: As Chris says, the Bootstrap team [explicitly requests](http://getbootstrap.com/about/) that people do not refer to it as "Twitter Bootstrap". That tag needs to burn, whatever we settle on.

Comment: @JeremyBanks I honestly think that is selfish of the Bootstrap Team. What makes them think they have the right to hijack the definition of "Bootstrap"? To me, Bootstrap is and always will be the technique of running procedures when an app starts, and I hope new programmers will realize that too.

Comment: @gitsitgo I'm sure there are apaches who think it sucks that people now think they are web servers. Not much you can do, and there is a reason projects are named after things and concepts.

Comment: @gitsitgo Twitter called the framework bootstrap because it provides a common set of tools and components that you can use to start building your custom web application on top of. What makes people think that they can hijack the definition of bootstrap to mean starting an application rather than pulling on one's boot by it's straps...

Comment: @MatthewPurdon The difference is, people learning programming will never get confused with actual bootstraps as they are not even remotely related. People learning programming _will_ get confused with framework bootstrap and application bootstrap process, as evident by OP's discovery of the massive misuse of the "bootstrap" tag.

Comment: @gitsitgo That's not evidence of your claim, it's just evidence that people don't attempt to disambiguate tags before choosing them, which is well-established.

Comment: It's also *completely irrelevant* to the question at hand here. Whether you think it's "selfish" or not doesn't change how we should handle these tags.

Answer (score 6):

As the Bootstrap Framework originated at Twitter, but is not named Twitter Bootstrap (anymore) I believe the tag should be:

[bootstrap-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap-framework)

And components of the framework should follow suit:

[bootstrap-framework-xxx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap-framework-xxx)

Answer (score 4):

It's worth noting that at least a few of your examples are separate projects that build on the Bootstrap framework; Multiselect, WYSIWYG, Growl, and Tour are the easiest for me to spot. The JavaScript components are also technically capable of being used in a (mostly) stand-alone fashion, so it makes some sense to have separate tags for them.

What might make sense is editing the tags to something like [twbs-bootstrap-modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twbs-bootstrap-modal), etc., which might help line the tags up with the [Github project's](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap) name.

If the point of your question was "there's more to 'bootstrap' than a CSS framework," I wholeheartedly agree. It's a similar issue we have with the ASP.NET MVC tag - I see more than a few questions tagged with the pattern tag, [model-view-controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/model-view-controller), rather than the specific framework tag, [aspnet-mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aspnet-mvc).

Answer (score 3):

In answer to the question itself, I don't see the need to add anything more verbose to the conjunction tags. I do think they should be cleaned up to be consistent. (e.g. [twitter-bootstrap-tooltip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap-tooltip) should become [bootstrap-tooltip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap-tooltip))

There's also the issue that [twitter-bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap) no longer refers to itself formally as such, having dropped the "twitter" portion except where it continues to persist as a seemingly more and more deprecated holdover. While it's still owned and licensed by Twitter, direct references to that seem to have largely been scrubbed from its own pages other than in the license itself. Most people I know who are just getting started with Bootstrap have to have the Twitter connection pointed out/explained to them, these days. They just know it (rightly or not) as "Bootstrap," not "Twitter Bootstrap."

Alphabetically (yes, I know, who does that? still…) most newer designers/devs are probably going to be looking in the 'b's, not the 't's, for anything related.

Between the fact that [bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap) by and large is understood to refer to the framework more than anything else (see below the <hr>), I think the added specificity in the conjunction tags is going to be easily understood to be within the context of the web framework for nearly all of the ones listed. There are at best one or two of those that *might* be very slightly ambiguous if we didn't start from that premise, but again, I think the shift in the general usage of "bootstrap" probably pairs that down to an absolute minimum.

As much as I'm for clarity in tagging, I'm not sure there's a need for added length in those conjunction tags: I have a feeling they're clear enough as they need to be as such.

---

This started as a comment in the thread on @Tanner's answer, but went beyond that context. Consider it a corollary to @Tanner's answer.

The ultimate point of any tagging system is semantic clarity. If we start from there (including looking at actual observed usage as @Tanner did), then I think this becomes relatively straightforward.

[bootstrapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrapping) (or its corollary: [bootstrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrapper)) is as unambiguous in what it refers to as possible, in a programming/software design context. More importantly, it fairly explicitly refers to a related design *pattern* (since it is directly based on the more general/business/colloquial language use that fits to/inspired that same pattern).

[bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap) is now, to me, relatively ambiguous in "general" programming related work, and in broader contexts (see: google results of each term) is nearly always colloquially (or technically, in web specific contexts) going to be understood now as referring to the associated framework. Fighting drift in colloquial language is fairly pointless, and since the associated drift is creeping into technical definitions/field specific jargon, it's probably time to look forward on this instead of back. I would personally immediately assume anything tagged with [bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap) and any other web related tag was intended to refer to the framework, not the generalized concept.

So in addition to @Tanner's empirical evidence based argument, I would also say that as a matter of semantic clarity and precision, [bootstrapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrapping) should be used to refer to the software/design concept of employing a [bootstrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrapper) (and related problems), and [bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap) should at best be used to refer to the web framework, if it isn't simply burnt (I would personally prefer [bootstrap-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap-framework), or something similar to be used instead so as to remain as unambiguous as possible on the exact topic it's meant to refer to—even the now somewhat less apparent to all [twitter-bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap) would be better).

As a personal aside, using [bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap) to refer to a [bootstrapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrapping) or at best [bootstrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrapper) question would have felt very unwieldy to me. That intermediate shortening (between the full wording of "Bootstrapping/Bootstrapper/Bootloader" and the most paired down form of "Boot") is one I honestly haven't heard used much in that context with anyone I personally talk to. If I was looking for answers related to bootstrapping coding issues, I wouldn't personally have looked at the [bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap) tag. The plural of anecdote isn't data, but I think @Tanner's empirical work and search results from google tend to point to that not being a completely uncommon viewpoint, at least.