# Make [bootstrap-4] a synonym of [twitter-bootstrap-4] (Or burninate it)?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request, tag-synonym-process

I do not have the rep to suggest a synonym, but should we not make [bootstrap-4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap-4) a synonym on [twitter-bootstrap-4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap-4), or even burninate it?

**Edit:** It seems there is already some discussion on the ambiguity of [bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap) and related tags in this [Meta Post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250920/bootstrap-tags-revisited). This proposes to re-organize all the [bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap) tags, though it does not look like it is going to happen since the post has not been active for a fair few months. I think we should use **@BAR**'s [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250920/bootstrap-tags-revisited), though this will take some effort

Comment: Since it's not called Twitter Bootstrap anymore...Bootstrap 4 should be the **primary**..and TB4 buriniated/or made a synonym

Comment: @Paulie_D If you think that is the right direction, then the general [tag:twitter-bootstrap] tag also needs changing and the tag wiki fixing.

Comment: Also I'm pretty sure it was purposely left to include the Twitter prefix as `bootstrap` is an actual thing too (that existed loooong before Twitter!)

Comment: Well **I** do...it hasn't been called *Twitter* Bootstrap for some time but people still remember it as that.

Comment: @Paulie_D Note there is history regarding this... https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250920/bootstrap-tags-revisited

Comment: Indeed...the problem persists.

Comment: @DavidG Nice link. I see there is a lot of confusion with the [tag:bootstrap] tags. The mods really need to sort it out, or decide what to do.

Comment: Thank you for posting this burnination request and allowing the community to take a close look at it. Please note that burninations are not just tag removals - They are the process of carefully moderating a specific place of Stack Overflow. Avoid mass-editing the tag out of questions as it is counter-productive. For more information, see [Shog9's answer on MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/306392) or the [unofficial SOCVR process](https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/SOCVR-RoomInformation/blob/master/burnination.md#process).

Comment: Burnination is more complex than just removing tags from questions, what you should wait for is widespread community approval via an upvoted answer in favour of burninating this tag. It can take a while.

Comment: IMO BAR's answer to the [Meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250920/bootstrap-tags-revisited) should be the answer to all the Bootstrap issues.

Comment: Please just for the love of the mighty Skeet, don't create a [bootstrap] tag again.

Comment: @j08691 I agree with you. Though it will take some hard work

Comment: It's very confusing, because bootstrap is in one hand, the boot sequence, and on the other, the name of the library... What should we do if one day, a new library is baptized 'ram' ? Should we remove the tag 'ram' who is used about memory by one about this new library ?
In my case I think it's a bad idea, but it's a subjective point of view....

Comment: @Put12co22mer2 [tag:ram-library] would do it. In this case, we either rename [tag:twitter-bootstrap] to [tag:bootstrap-library] or just accept it was once associated with Twitter. Personally I'm not all that bothered which way it goes!

Comment: Another consideration, besides `twitter-bootstrap` there's also tags for `twitter-bootstrap-2`, `twitter-bootstrap-3` and `twitter-bootstrap-4`.. and the `bootstrap` tag previously got oddles of posts relating to "twitter bootstrap" and not this definition of "[bootstrap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping)" __ as @j08691 said (this has already [been discussed here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250920/bootstrap-tags-revisited)

Comment: I just came across [this](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13698644) in the review queue: someone adding `bootstrap-4` in addition to the already present `twitter-bootstrap-4`… but also mentioning that it is actually [recommended on the official site](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap#community)!

Answer (score 0):

I don’t have enough score in these tags to suggest synonyms but the longer nothing is done about this issue, the messier the situation gets. I figured I’d post an answer (as suggested by @Kyll in the comments) in the hope of getting some community approval on this issue.

With regards to time sensitivity: one user (with less than 2k reputation) has been searching for all posts with the `twitter-bootstrap-4` tag and adding the `bootstrap-4` tag to those posts (sometimes removing the `twitter-bootstrap-4`, most times retaining the pre-existing tags).  They’ve made over 30 such edits (which don’t improve the questions in any other way) over the past week and most (if not all) of these edits have been approved.  The justification provided for these edits is.

> bootstrap-4 is the official tag see https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap#community.

When I came across one of these in the *Suggested Edits* review queue, earlier today, I searched on Meta to see what the best practice is for such tags and this was the most relevant post I saw. As a result, I rejected that particular edit with the following custom reason:

> There's no consensus on this yet: [Make [bootstrap-4] a synonym of [twitter-bootstrap-4] (Or burninate it)?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320458/make-bootstrap-4-a-synonym-of-twitter-bootstrap-4-or-burninate-it)

---

### Proposals

For what it’s worth, I see that the generic `tag:bootstrap` has already been burninated (even though the term has many other meanings outside the field of front-end web development).  In this specific case – Version 4 of the (ex-Twitter) Bootstrap Framework) – there’s no need for burnination as the tags do serve a useful purpose and synonymising is sufficient to clear up the confusion.  Both of the tags being discussed in this question were created in February this year and both of them have useful content in their wikis but it’s clear that they serve the same purpose.

I propose that the contents of their tag wikis should be merged and …

1. I prefer BAR’s answer in the [generic bootstrap thread](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250920/bootstrap-tags-revisited) (using [bootstrap-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap-framework)). I propose that both [bootstrap-4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap-4) and [twitter-bootstrap-4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap-4) become synonyms of [bootstrap-framework-4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap-framework-4)).

or …

2. Proposal 2 has been split into a separate answer so if people prefer it, they can vote on that answer.

For consistency, it would make sense that the other version numbers (2 and 3) are similarly synonymised afterwards. Regardless, the community, moderators and/or high-rep users should reach *some* consensus and communicate with the framework authors so everyone is using (or recommending the use of) one tag.

Comment: Would it make sense for me to split Proposals 1 and 2 into two separate answers so people can vote for one over the other?

Answer (score 0):

*This proposal has been split from my first answer so that if people prefer this idea, they can upvote this answer instead of the original.*

### Proposal 2

I’d advocate, as a short-term solution, that [twitter-bootstrap-4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap-4) be made a synonym for [bootstrap-4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap-4) – after merging the content from the tag wikis. The version number in the tag makes it obvious that the tag refers to a framework rather than the general concept.

Comment: I don't have enough rep on [Bootstrap-4] either. But making them synonyms seems like the clear idea. I am assuming the questions would be merged once the synonyms are approved.