# "bootstrapping" tag description is not clear enough for new users

Tags: discussion, tags

I have spent lots of time in the past clearing up questions that misuse the [bootstrapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrapping) tag. Lots of users use this tag for [twitter-bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap) questions, even though it says clearly at the bottom of the description not to use it in this circumstance.

I think that this needs to be a little bit clearer (put this message at the beginning of the tag description instead of the end) or even add an alert when [twitter-bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap) and [bootstrapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrapping) tags are in the same question (just a warning that can be dismissed).

Does anyone else feel the same way?

Comment: I hate to be pessimistic but it really won't help.  We have tags that start with DO NOT USE... and they are still used daily.

Comment: @NathanOliver so maybe the alert idea

Comment: I don't think anything short of an alert would have any chance of having a significant impact. Warnings in tag descriptions may help, but as my experience retagging questions incorrectly tagged with [tag:requirejs] suggests, people don't pay much attention to descriptions. I can't say I saw a significant difference in mistaggings even after I edited [tag:requirejs]' description to try to warn people against incorrect usage.

Comment: related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250920/bootstrap-tags-revisited?rq=1

Comment: Is that caused by the blacklisting of bootstrap: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309933/we-gave-bootstrap-the-boot-but-it-wasnt-heavy-enough ?

Comment: @rene I knew there was something about this... *sigh*... the real solution is to blacklist *both*.

Comment: can we just synonyms `bootstrap-framework` or `bootstrap-twitter` to `twitter-bootstrap` that s so people typing bootstrap can discovery the correct one easily?

Comment: @BryanChen yeah sounds like a good idea

Comment: @BryanChen how would we go about changing it?

Comment: Vote synonyms [here](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/twitter-bootstrap/synonyms) or wait until a mod to do it

Comment: I think the tag description is very poor. Bootstrapping is used in many context, e.g. the writing of a compiler for a new programing language or during boot of a device. The tag description only mentions the start of an application and web request (I have never seen it used in the latter context). 
So all in all, that tags desperately needs an overhaul.

Comment: @Polygome I think it's wrong. Bootstrapping refers to operating systems, compiler construction, Tomcat and JVM starts, but I've never seen it used in connection with application startup in 45 years, or web requests either for that matter.